# Is it possible to use one QFrame several times?

Tags: qt, separator, qframe

I am using a QWidget in which I would like to put some separator lines.
As separator lines I am using this

```
QFrame *seperatorLine = new QFrame(_toolBar);
seperatorLine->setFrameStyle(QFrame::Sunken | QFrame::VLine);
```

I need several separator lines and I was curious whether I need to create a new `QFrame` every time or whether there is a way to reuse one (or use a copy-constructor).

At the moment the line is only at the last position I added it to the `QWidget`.

Comment: I believe each GUI element should be represented by a separate instance of `QFrame` (QWidget), so you need several separator lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`QObject` and thus `QWidget` derived class cannot access a copy constructor.

Instead of that, you can encapuslate your QFrame property in a little factory method:

```
QFrame* createSeparator(QWidget* parent=0) {
    QFrame *separatorLine = new QFrame(parent);
    separatorLine->setFrameStyle(QFrame::Sunken | QFrame::VLine);
    return separatorLine;
}
```

I prefer this method over subclassing QFrame to tweak several properties of a QFrame instance

A fancy way to "clone" a QObject would be to create a new object and assign all declared properties. Of course it is only useful if you want to transfer values:

```
CustomObject* CustomObject::clone() {
    int count = metaObject()->propertyCount();
    CustomObject* clone = new CustomObject(this->parent());

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        const char* prop = metaObject()->property(i).name();
        clone->setProperty(prop, property(prop));
    }
    return clone;
}
```

Comment: thanks, this works.
I thought about this solution, but wanted to know if there is any fancy Qt-way.
I mistyped `separatorLine`. You may want to change it in your answer.